# Replace each white space in string with number of whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have below challenge.  I need to replace each space in string with a number that indicates how many spaces are there. 
Eg: "Hello World  !"; should be modified to "Hello1World2!";
 How do I achieve this in c#. Please help

Comment: What were your initial ideas? Have you tried something? You seem to be searching in the direction of regex (=> tag). What made you think this is a good idea and do you want answers to go into regex solutions, only? Please help us help you.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs. _Also, be clear as to what you mean by `whitespaces` - does that mean just space? What about tab? Carriage return? etc etc_

Comment: You tagged the question with RegEx, but neither your question, nor your title states if RegEx is really a requirement. Is it?

Comment: @PaulKertscher ith think SKN believes that this task might be solved with regular expressions

Comment: @MarcoForberg That's why Paul is asking - so we need not "think he does" but we can "know he does" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And i finally got a regex-answer:
use the `MatchEvaluator`-class of regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string input = "bla absl ael   dls ale ";

    var result2 = Regex.Replace(input, "\s+", new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceByCount));
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
    //returns bla1absl1ael3dls1ale1
}

private static string ReplaceByCount(Match m)
{
    return m.Value.Length.ToString();
}
```

Edit: replaced " +" with "\s+" to match all whitespace characters after @Marco-Forbergs comment

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use "\s+" to find other whitespace characters as well?

Comment: Thanks for the generous help. My initial attempt was to find all the spaces( just space) using regex '\s+'. However I had no idea how do I replace it with number of spaces. Thanks @Chriz . I learnt about MatchEvaluator today.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this works for you:

```
string testString = "Hello World  !   ";
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int charCount = 0;

foreach(char character in testString)
{
    if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
    {
        charCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(charCount > 0)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(charCount);
            charCount = 0;
        }
        resultBuilder.Append(character);
    }
}

if (charCount > 0)
{
    resultBuilder.Append(charCount);
    charCount = 0;
}

testString = resultBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //your base string value
        string baseString = "Hello World !";

        for (int i = 0; i < baseString.Length; i++)
        {
            //check if have empty sumbol by position in string
            if (baseString[i] == ' ')
            {
                //replace symbol logic
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(baseString);
                //here you can add logic for random number
                sb[i] = '1';
                baseString = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the number of spaces (' ' = 1, '   ' = 3 (should be 3 spaces in a row..)?) oder the first space is 1 the second is 2 etc.?

If it is the "index"-number of each space try this:

```
private void SpaceNumber()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int sc = 1;
    string input = "bla absldf el kdslf ael dls ale xyz";

    foreach (string x in input.Split(' '))
    {
        sb.Append(x);
        sb.Append(sc);
        sc++;
    }

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    string output = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to help you.
I'm at work with no dev tools available, so consider this as pseudo code:

```
string testString = "Hello World !";
int spaceCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<testString.length; i++)
{
    if (testString.charAt(i) == " ")
    {
        spaceCounter++;
        testString.CharAt(i) = spaceCounter.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers!

And here's my turn :

```
        string theWords = "Hello World of C Sharp!";
        int i = 1;

        int pos = theWords.IndexOf(' ');
        while (pos >= 0)
        {
            theWords = theWords.Substring(0, pos) + i.ToString() + theWords.Substring(pos + 1);
            pos = theWords.IndexOf(' ');
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ solution:

```
string str = "Hello World !";

string result = str.Split()
                .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, str.Split().Length), (x, y) => x + y)
                .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y).Remove(str.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It seems a few difficult but with great perserverance it's OK. I advise you to use the **StringBuilder class of C#** (so don't miss to add the assembly matching).

So this is the script you can get the result :

```
string entry = "Hello World !";

StringBuilder stringToBuild = new StringBuilder(entry);
int iForNewValue = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < entry.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ITEM [{0}] at {1}", entry[i], i);
    if (entry[i].ToString() == " ")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=======> SPACE FOUNDED HERE");
        stringToBuild.Replace(entry[i].ToString(), iForNewValue++.ToString(), i, 1);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("NEW STRING BUILD ========================> {0}", stringToBuild);
```